# Count one-time occurrence values on a column, given another column values

Tags: python, pandas, count, duplicates, dataset

So, I have this kind of dataset:
df=

```
Id    Pos        Salary  year
                               
00    Chief      2000    2003
01    Assistant  1800    2003
02    Assistant  1950    2003
03    Analyst    5200    2003
04    Guard      1000    2003
05    Chief      2500    2004
06    Service     800    2003
07    Exec      10000    2005
08    Exec      12000    2005
09    Sales      1100    2007
```

And I'm asked to count how many '`Pos`' were held by only one person in 2003. (for this example that would be 4, since pos 'Assistant' was held by 2 people)

By running

`(df.duplicated(subset=['Pos'], keep=False)).sum()`

I get the count of single occurrences without taking into account the column '`year`'

I tried

`(df.duplicated(subset=['Pos', 'year'], keep=False)).sum()`

But then it counts the single occurrences for both `pos` and `years`. (Six in total: 4 for positions held by only one person for all years, plus 2, for rows that don't repeat in 'year')

I believe I need to use a df.groupby, but I wouldn't be sure of the syntaxis. Any Ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `df.loc[df["year"].eq(2003),"Pos"].drop_duplicates(keep=False).nunique()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first extract a subset of rows with `year == 2003` before you find duplicates.
Also you need to inverse the results before computing the sum, because `duplicated` will mark duplicate occurrences as True, whereas you need sum of unique occurrences.
Try this:
`(~(df[df.year==2003].duplicated(subset=['Pos'], keep=False))).sum()`

Comment: ´(~(df[df.year==2003].duplicated(subset=['Pos'], keep=False))).sum()´ did the job.Though I thought the "~" operator was already inverting the "true" results. Thanks for your help